# Copy table rows into new table with multiple criteria - only copies first row?

Tags: excel, criteria, paste, expand

I have a project that I'm hoping some of you can help me out with where I'm going wrong. Here's the scoop:

I have an Excel worksheet with a table that contains a lot of data. I need to copy rows of data based on multiple criteria and paste it into another table in a different worksheet. The second table should expand to accommodate however many rows of information there is. Something like this (assuming these are tables in Excel):

```
   |    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |
|1 |Name^    |Fruit^   |Amount^  |Strata^  |
|2 |Mary     |Apples   |300      |Sand     |
|3 |Dean     |Oranges  |200      |Gravel   |
|4 |Mary     |Bananas  |300      |Sand     |
|5 |Sam      |Oranges  |200      |Loam     |
|6 |Mary     |Oranges  |200      |Sand     |
|7 |Dean     |Apples   |500      |Loam     |
```

If a row contains Mary in the first column and 300 in the third column, that row should be copied to the new table in a different worksheet which would then look like:

```
   |    A    |    B    |    C    |    D    |
|1 |Name^    |Fruit^   |Amount^  |Strata^  |
|2 |Mary     |Apples   |300      |Sand     |
|3 |Mary     |Bananas  |300      |Sand     |
```

The problem I'm running into is that I can get the rows to copy, but they do so below the second table, or I can get only the first row of data to paste into the new table. The code thus far is:

```
Public Sub CopyRows()
    ' Select starting sheet with data table
    Sheets("Full data").Select

    ' loop through all rows
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 8).Value
        ' Set filtering criteria and copy matching cells
        If Cells(x, 8) = "PHONE" And Cells(x, 14) = "v" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
            ' Select sheet where second table is located
            Sheets("By Phone, Verified").Select
            ' Select the second table
            Range("Table2[Company]").Select
            ListObject = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            ' paste the rows of data
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

The second table starts with only a header and one row and both tables start on the 3rd row of their sheet.

Any ideas how I can get the copied data into the second table? Let me know if any more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your full table structure I would guess that the last `ActiveSheet.Paste` is repeatedly pasting new rows over the old ones.

Try running the macro step by step using `F8` in the VB Editor and watching what is selected and where it is pasted.

Two suggestions;

1. For smaller data sets use the `for i` loop and try changing your `paste` command to an `insert` so that new rows are added at the top of the results table.
2. For larger data sets avoid using the loop. Instead use a filter to select all the rows you need, copy the filtered results and paste these.

From experience the loop method is easier to write, but slow over large data sets. I would suggest something like;

```
'Clear any existing filters from Stats
Sheets("Full Data").Select

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False


'Apply the filter(s)
'Range references should be absolute $A$1:$Z$26
'Field refers to the column number within that range
'Find non-blank columns with Criteria "<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("<<your source range>>").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Mary"
ActiveSheet.Range("<<your source range>>").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="300"

'Select and copy the rows
'Use A1:D1 to include headers or A2:D2 to exclude
Range("A1:D1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

'Paste into your results

'Remember to come back and clear the filters afterwards
Sheets("Full Data").Select

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks CJC, I've found that the code:

```
Public Sub CopyRows()
    Sheets("Full data").Select
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
    If Cells(x, 8) = "PHONE" And Cells(x, 14) = "v" Then
    Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, 33).Copy
        Sheets("By Phone, Verified").Select
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Sheets("Full data").Select
    End If
Next x    
End Sub
```

Does what I want, but will not paste the rows into a table. You're definitely right that it is extremely slow and with over 5K rows being split different ways into about ten worksheets, it's going to be an all day event! If there's a better way to do it with filtering I'd be all for it.